# javascript min heap implementation for a storing a pair/tuple

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tuples, min-heap

I created a class to implement a min heap following a tutorial. It works fine for storing and retrieving integers. I want to store pairs in this class for example:
(5, 1)
(2, 4)
(6, 2)

The removeMin method should give (2, 4) back. Please find the class below:

```
class MinHeap {
    constructor() {
        this.storage = [];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    getLeftChildIndex(index) {
        return 2 * index + 1;
    }

    getRightChildIndex(index) {
        return 2 * index + 2;
    }
    // check if this rounds down
    getParentIndex(index) {
        return Math.floor((index - 1) / 2)
    }

    hasLeftChild(index) {
        return this.getLeftChildIndex(index) < this.size;
    }

    hasRightChild(index) {
        return this.getRightChildIndex(index) < this.size;
    }

    hasParent(index) {
        return this.getParentIndex(index) >= 0;
    }

    leftChild(index) {
        return this.storage[this.getLeftChildIndex(index)];
    }

    rightChild(index) {
        return this.storage[this.getRightChildIndex(index)];
    }

    parent(index) {
        return this.storage[this.getParentIndex(index)];
    }

    isFull() {
        return this.size == this.capacity;
    }

    swap(index1, index2) {
        let temp = this.storage[index1];
        this.storage[index1] = this.storage[index2];
        this.storage[index2] = temp;
    }

    insert(data) {
        this.storage[this.size] = data;
        this.size += 1;
        this.heapifyUp();
    }

    heapifyUp() {
        let index = this.size - 1;
        while (this.hasParent(index) &&
            this.parent(index) > this.storage[index]) {
            this.swap(this.getParentIndex(index), index);
            index = this.getParentIndex(index);
        }
    }

    removeMin() {
        // if (this.size == 0)
        //     throw new Error("Empty Heap");
        let data = this.storage[0];
        this.storage[0] = this.storage[this.size - 1];
        this.size -= 1;
        this.heapifyDown();
        return data;
    }

    heapifyDown() {
        let index = 0;
        while (this.hasLeftChild(index)) {
            let smallerChildIndex = this.getLeftChildIndex(index);
            if (this.hasRightChild(index) && this.rightChild(index) < this.leftChild(index))
                smallerChildIndex = this.getRightChildIndex(index);
            if (this.storage[index] < this.storage[smallerChildIndex])
                break;
            else
                this.swap(index, smallerChildIndex);
            index = smallerChildIndex;
        }
    }

    getTop() {
        return this.storage[0];
    }
}
```

Could anyone please suggest changes to the above class to store and retrieve pairs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort your pairs by first element and then second, you would need to implement the comparison and swap operators for your int-pairs. You could store int-pairs as a 2-long array of int.